# Create VM without OS with Vagrant

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

For testing of automated OS deploy on a hardware cluster, I need Vagrant to create few VMs without OS installed, with just network boot enabled.

I succesfully created base box image and configured boot order with Vagrant.

Problem is that Vagrant dies after waiting for VM to boot (which it doesn't, because it has nothing to boot), trying to set up ssh forwarding, shared folders etc.

Is there any way I can tell Vagrant to just power on the machine and not try to configure or boot it?

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant's idea is to manage already installed boxes. It has some requirements for them. SSH or other login access is a fundamental one.

If you just want to spin up a VirtualBox VM, you can call VBoxManage etc. directly.